# easily make labels look nice pandas plotting

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

See screenshot. I have a DataTime index, a dataframe which I've resampled to quarterly, but when I graph only the end of the datetimes show up and it's 00.00.00 for all of them because they're precise to the second.

Any tips?  Code here (using Jupyter with Vagrant on MacOS):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib nbagg
pd.options.display.mpl_style = 'default'

#get
df = pd.read_csv('MC_720_061813_071715.CSV')
#format
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.drop(['Status', 'Date'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
df.fillna(0, inplace = True)
df.Credit = df.Credit.apply(lambda x: float(str(x).replace(',','')))
#process
df2 = df.resample('Q', how = sum)
#graph
df2.plot(kind = 'bar')
```

[image: matplotlib plot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply rename those ticklabels on x-axis.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.options.display.mpl_style = 'default'

# generate some artificial data
# ======================================
date_rng = np.random.choice(pd.date_range('2012-01-01', '2015-12-31', freq='D'), 2000)
val = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=2000)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': date_rng, 'Credit':val}).set_index('Date').sort_index()

# before: same problem as you saw
# ======================================
df.resample('Q', how=sum).plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

```
# processing
# ======================================
df1 = df.resample('Q', how=sum)
labels = ['{}Q{}'.format(y,q) for y,q in zip(df1.index.year, df1.index.quarter)]
ax = df1.plot(kind='bar')
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

[image]